# Issue While Copying Data from a Oracle Siebel View using ADF

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-data-factory, siebel

I am using a copy activity to copy data from a force siebel into adls gen2 in parquet format.

I am sung the Following query

`SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.VIEWNAME`

But I am encountering the Following Error from ADF

`Odbc Operation Failed.`
`ERROR [22008] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-01843: 指定した月が無効です。`

Which Translates to The specified month is invalid.

I have also tried selecting a single column from the view which is of type varchar. But still ADF gave the same error message as response.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide the source connector details? What is the source? Show the linked service settings/